# When declare array, what value hold on their memory address

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

If not declare value in an array, then what value hold on the memory address.

Where did these outputs come from?

```
int main()  
{
int a[10];
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[2]<<endl;
cout<<a[3]<<endl;
cout<<a[3]<<endl;
return 0; 
}
//Given Output
//1978190368
//1978190368
//1129149863
//1129149863
```

Comment: It's undefined, anyvalue.

Comment: Then, Where did these outputs come from?

Comment: Most probably garbage left from other program runs.

Comment: But it gives me same output for same key. Then, how it is garbage?

Comment: Physical memory always contains *something*, and it always contains the last thing that was written there.

Comment: In C++ arrays are indexed from ***zero*** to `n - 1`. So for `int a[10];` the valid indexes are `{0, 1, 2, 3, ..... 9}` Where do you assign any value to any element of the array? You didn't initialize the array as all zeros, e.g. `int a[10] = {0};`. At least then your would avoid Undefined Behavior, but all elements would be zero (not very exciting). Why not `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i] = i * 2;` Now the array is initialized to all even-numbers less than `20`. Until a variable is initialized, they just contain garbage-values. `1978190368` looks like a good garbage value to me.

Comment: I give you a box that you can store things in, but I also left something in it that I don't care about any more. I don't tell you what it is, and you don't replace the contents. Do you expect the box to contain different things every time you look inside it, or will it just be whatever I put there?

Comment: What you did there was declaring a local array on the stack frame of the current function (main). The content of the array members is whatever was written to the addresses at the stack frame before the declaration of the array.